# read GetStorage data inside GetxController

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I use **GetStorage** to store user data
, I want to read its data in **user profile GetxController**

```js
 class UserHomeController extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage();
  // I found this method    **but**   i can't convert it to object
  // as   User get user => (userFromJson(GetStorage().read<User>('user'))
  String get userS => (GetStorage().read<String?>('user') ?? "");

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, you can directly read the data using read method with key name:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';


class Controller extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage();
  bool get isDark => box.read('darkmode') ?? false;
  ThemeData get theme => isDark ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light();
  void changeTheme(bool val) => box.write('darkmode', val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest
..I have found this way through research as explained in my question
But I stored the user object as a string That's why I want to convert to object again in the get event ,
 I tried the following method but it gives me an error
User get user => (userFromJson(GetStorage().read<User>('user'))

Comment: write this
User get user => (userFromJson(box.read('user'))

Answer (score 0):

```
 class UserHomeController extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage();
   //Change the following line
   // String get userS => (GetStorage().read<String?>('user') ?? "");
   // to
   String get userS => (box.read('user') ?? "");

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
  }
```